# c: ls -l implementation gives undefined behavior

Tags: c

So for an assignment I need to implement the ls -l functionality in c. I am trying to get all the information into an string array so I can manipulate the data later. It prints out fine within the while loop, but it breaks if i try to print my contents array else where. What would cause this error?

```
int getContentsLong(const char *dir, char **contents)
{
    DIR *dp = NULL;
    struct dirent *dptr = NULL;
    struct stat fileStat;

    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        return -1;  
    }   
    dp = opendir(dir);
    if (dp == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int cnt = 0;
    char toRtn[512];
    char path[256];
    while ((dptr = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    {   
        strcpy(path, dir);
        strcat(path, "/");
        strcat(path, dptr->d_name);
        stat(path, &fileStat);
        strcpy(path, " ");

        //getting l info
        //permissions
        toRtn[0] =    ((S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode)) ? 'd' : '-');
        strcat(toRtn, (fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");
        strcat(toRtn, (fileStat.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");
        strcat(toRtn, (fileStat.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");
        strcat(toRtn, (fileStat.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-");
        strcat(toRtn, (fileStat.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-");
        strcat(toRtn, (fileStat.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-");
        strcat(toRtn, (fileStat.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-");
        strcat(toRtn, (fileStat.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-");
        strcat(toRtn, (fileStat.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? "x" : "-");
        strcat(toRtn, " ");

        //links
        char tmp[sizeof(long int)];
        sprintf(tmp, "%d", fileStat.st_nlink); 
        strcat(toRtn, tmp);
        strcat(toRtn, " ");

        //owner and group names
        struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(fileStat.st_uid);
        struct group  *gr = getgrgid(fileStat.st_gid);      
        if (pw != 0) strcat(toRtn, pw->pw_name);
        strcat(toRtn, " ");
        if (gr != 0) strcat(toRtn, gr->gr_name);
        strcat(toRtn, " ");

        //filesize
        strcpy(tmp, " ");
        sprintf(tmp, "%ld", fileStat.st_size);
        strcat(toRtn, tmp);
        strcat(toRtn, " "); 

        //last access time
        strcpy(tmp, " ");
        strftime(tmp, 200, "%b %d %H:%M", localtime(&fileStat.st_atime));
        strcat(toRtn, tmp);
        strcat(toRtn, " ");

        //file/dir name
        strcat(toRtn, dptr->d_name);
        strcat(toRtn, " ");

        //strcpy(contents[cnt], toRtn);
        contents[cnt] = toRtn;  
        printf("%s\n", contents[cnt]);  

        strcpy(toRtn, " ");
        cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

The output I get from the

```
   printf("%s\n", contents[cnt]);
```

line is:

```
drwxr-xr-x 30 justin justin 4096 Nov 22 20:18 .. 
drwxr-xr-x 2 justin justin 4096 Nov 22 20:18 . 
-rw-r--r-- 1 justin justin 5676 Nov 22 20:18 ls.c 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 justin justin 12172 Nov 22 20:18 ls
```

but when I print

```
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
{
    printf("%s ", contents[i]);
}
```

it doesn't display anything.
If I use the strcpy(content, toRtn); line I get a seg fault.

Comment: `char tmp[sizeof(long int)];` may be too small. `sizeof` doesn't mean "number of bytes in the decimal representation plus one"

Comment: `strftime(tmp, 200,` is also likely to overflow that buffer

Comment: `contents[cnt] = toRtn;` is bad, because `toRtn` is destroyed when the function returns, so if the caller goes on to inspect the value then it is undefined

Comment: @M.M Why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @Tim i don't like to answer without an MCVE . there are many possible errors. Maybe the calling code doesn't use `contents[cnt]`, who knows. too many unknowns to make a reliable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that, for various values of `cnt`.

```
contents[cnt] = toRtn;
```

is being used to (indirectly) return `toRtn` to the caller, where `toRtn` is a local array in the function, so ceases to exist when the function returns.

Which means, for the caller that the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
{
    printf("%s ", contents[i]);
}
```

repeatedly tries to print the contents of an array of `char` that no longer exists.   That gives undefined behaviour.

There are other fundamental concerns in your code too.  You need to better understand the relationship between pointers and arrays (they can be used interchangeably in some circumstances, but some of your code is using them interchangeably when they are not interchangeably) and the meaning of scope (returning the address of a local variable to the caller, by any means, is a bad idea since the variable will cease to exist when its containing function/scope ends).

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly many errors in this code.  Here is a flagrant error:

```
toRtn[0] =    ((S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode)) ? 'd' : '-');
// WAIT what about the NUL terminator?
strcat(toRtn, (fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");
```

Another error is here:

```
contents[cnt] = toRtn;
```

So *every* entry in `contents` will point to `toRtn` (i.e. `contents[0] == contents[1]` which I'm sure is not what you want) and these will all be dangling pointers (which is also not what you want).

Start by fixing these errors, maybe there are more.

Comment: Doesn't toRtn get changed everytime the while loop runs?

Comment: @shadowguard: its contents changes, but the array itself (and thus its address) is always the same.